# How do I use scanf to properly parse and filter dynamic input?

Tags: c, scanf

This is for homework, so I'm stuck with the requirements I describe.

I need to handle input of the following general form:

```
XYZ A1 5
```

The first part (`XYZ`) is a command, `A1` is an address (I only need the 1), and `5` is the value of the command. Additionally, I need to handle commands that have neither address nor value (just `XYZ`, for example), and commands that have only an address but no value (`XYZ A1`).

I managed to duck-tape this together which seems to handle everything *cough* pretty well:

```
n = scanf("%c%c%c A%i %i",&c1,&c2,&c3,&a,&val);
```

So I can use `n` (how many arguments/variables `scanf` managed to match) to figure out what sort of command it is, then do some basic checks to get what I need. And it works pretty well!

**But here is my problem:**
There is also a command in the format `XYZ A1 A2` - as in it has two 'address' values. How do I get `scanf` to parse this as well? Once again, I don't really need the 'A' to be parsed.

If I do:

```
scanf("%c%c%c A%i A%i",&c1,&c2,&c3,&a,&val);
```

then the various other commands wont work when the address and value inputs don't have an 'A' before them.

**P.S. Not allowed to use any form of strings / arrays, hence the chars;**

What can I do here?

Comment: I advise reading the input with `fgets` and then applying `sscanf`. Then when only, say, 2 of the 3 fields you request are present, it is easy to ignore the rest of the line and move on to the next. And scan for three *strings*, before analysing as many as were entered. Use the function return value from `sscanf`.

Comment: You could also use `%s` for the last one and parse that string afterwards (if it exists). But that's using a string/array and so is the above solution. Alternatively, you could use `%c%i` for the last one and check what the first char is.

Comment: Guyssss please read the post fully - not allowed any form of array, including string. Though I'll check out Weather Vane's first solution, that might be correct because it still uses some sort of scanf, thanks!

Comment: "Not allowed to use any form of strings" --> Note: `"%c%c%c A%i A%i"` is a string.

Comment: Do you need to be able to read a sequence of such instructions from the input, or do you only need to handle one?  Because running the `scanf()` you present in a loop will not do what you might expect.  Trailing whitespace (e.g. newlines) will trip it up.

Comment: Hey John, yes I have to loop it until a termination command is entered.

Comment: Just read the whole input as a string with `fgets`and then parse that. Anything else is rather questionable practice.

Comment: I know, but as I said many times before, I CANNOT use strings i.e. I have to parse letter by letter or not use char at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to do it all in a single `scanf` call.  Instead, read the command first, check if it takes additional parameters, then read those:

```
n = scanf( "%c%c%c", &c1, &c2, &c3 );
if ( n != 3 )
  // input error, bail out here

if ( has_address( c1, c2, c3 ) )
{
  if ( scanf( "A%i", &a1 ) != 1 )
    // input error, bail out here
}

if ( has_2nd_address( c1, c2, c3 ) )
{
  if ( scanf( "A%i", &a2 ) != 1 )
    // input error, bail out here
}

if ( has_value( c1, c2, c3 ) )
{
  if ( scanf( "%i", &val ) != 1 )
    // input error
}
```

`has_address`, `has_2nd_address`, and `has_value` are simply placeholders for whatever logic you need to use to determine whether you need to read one or two address, and whether you need to read a value.

Comment: Can't believe this didn't cross my mind, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `scanf("%c%c%c A%i %c%i",&c1,&c2,&c3,&a, &c4, &val);`, check if c4 is a digit, in which case you have a little bit more work to do to get the proper val, but not much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value.  If it is 4, the last number remains to be scanned.

```
// Add leading space to consume previous line's \n
int n = scanf(" %c%c%c A%i A%i", &c1, &c2, &c3, &a, &val);

switch (n) {
  case 5: Handle_XYZ_A1_A2(c1, c2, c3, a, val); break;
  case 4: // A not detected
    int n = scanf("%i", &val);
    if (n == 1) { Handle_XYZ_A1_2(c1, c2, c3, a, val); break; }
  default:
    Handle_Bad_Input();
}
```

Using `fgets()` first makes more sense, but seems to not be allowed given OP restrictions.